# How to drop rows with ALL zero values but not zeros WITH non zero values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with these values:

```
0,0,0,0,October 29 2018 16:35:04
0,1,2,0,October 30 2018 11:40:04
0,0,0,0,November 25 2018 04:20:13
```

I wanted to remove the rows with zero values on the first 4 columns:

```
0,0,0,0,October 29 2018 16:35:04 #remove this
0,1,2,0,October 30 2018 11:40:04 #this should stay
0,0,0,0,November 25 2018 04:20:13 #remove this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use `df[...]`:

```
print(df[~(df[df.columns[:4]]==0).all(1)])
```

Slightly better (thanks to @jpp), use `iloc`:

```
print((df.iloc[:, :4] == 0).all(1))
```

Both Output:

```
   0  1  2  3                         4
1  0  1  2  0  October 30 2018 11:40:04
```

Columns for output maybe incorrect, because i don't know the actual ones.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to do what you're asking, but you have a couple of tasks:

- read a .csv, you can do this with `csv.reader`
- go over all its contents, you can do this with a simple `for` loop
- check some conditions, you'll need to check if the integer value is 0, `int(row[col]) == 0`
- write lines that meet the conditions to a new .csv, you can do this with csv.writer

Here's a working script that does these things, without requiring external libraries, other than the standard `csv` one:

```
from csv import reader, writer

with open('input.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
        csv_in = reader(input_file)
        csv_out = writer(output_file)
        for row in csv_in:
            if not all([int(row[col]) == 0 for col in range(0, 4)]):
                csv_out.writerow(row)
```